# Why use 100E resistor in max232 ic in serial pins 13 and 14?

Tags: resistors, max232

[image]serial pin 13(RxD) use 100E -pin 13 to male connector pin 2(RxD), 
serial pin 14(TxD) use 100E -pin 14 to male connector pin 3(TxD)

Why 100E used?

I have attached image and mention clearly for your reference...

Comment: The scenario you paint is not a general scenario in MAX232 so be clear and post a schematic of what you mean.

Comment: ESD protection?

Comment: I dont know correct meaning, please tell about why it(100E) used and what purpose of used (100E)?

Comment: C5 is the wrong value , ie 1uF is in datasheet for an EMI reason

Comment: What does the E mean? I'm used to seeing 100 Ω or 100 R, but I've never seen E before. Is it from another language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, we can't know a specific reason why someone has put them there, but we can guess. They might be there to help the chip ESD protection to cope with even larger surges than without them. They might be there to help to decrease EMI from conducting and radiating from wires. They might be there to slow down signal edges. They might provide some protection for overvoltage situations. They might be there just because this is copied from somewhere else, so there is really no reason.